# Why does Android Studio 3.1.1 always display Unresolved reference when I reopen a project for the first time?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have `import info.dodata.mirror.R`, I always get the warning information `Unresolved reference: R` when I reopen a project for the first time, just like the following image.

I have to click the menu  Build -> Rebuild project to rebuild the project, or I close the project and reopen it again in Android Studio 3.1.1 to resolve the problem.

Both my office PC and home PC with windows 7 x64 meet the same problem. How can I fix it? Thanks!

**Image**

[image]

**To ice1000:**

Thanks! 
Do you mean that I should click Refresh All Gradle Projects button?
[image]

Comment: BTW, both my two PC are 8G memory, i7-4600 CPU 2.4GHZ, windows 7 x64,  are my PCs too old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `R.java` is generated from your resource xml files, and it's not always there. It takes few seconds to get generated.

I don't know how Android Studio resolves that file, but it's also possibly just a dummy file which is not there when you're not compiling your code. So it's quite normal to see unresolved reference in the very beginning when AS load your project.

To quickly get your project refreshed you may need `refresh` your project instead of `rebuild` it:

[image: Wow]

If you can't find that button, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+Shift</kbd>+A</kbd>, you'll see a popup, and you can search `refresh`:

[image]

Comment: In fact, few seconds passed, Android Studio still display Unresolved reference, you know that Rebuild Project will take a long time

Comment: It's a bad point of Android Studio's internal implementation. You don't need to rebuild, you just need "refresh" which doesn't actually compile your code but reloads all the settings.

Comment: Thanks! How to  "refresh" ?

Comment: I can't find  "refresh"  button on Android Studio

Comment: Thanks! would you please see my modified question?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.